# Openpyxl load_workbook and save take too long

Tags: python, openpyxl

The following lines take 45 seconds the first, and over a minute and a half the second. Something.xls is 4 MB big and the changes are minor. Is there something wrong?

```
something = openpyxl.load_workbook('Something.xlsx')
something.save('Something.xlsx')
```

Some details: I'm using Python 2.7.3 on Windwos 7, the workbook has 2 sheets the first of which has 67610 rows, I'm not accesing any network to do this job.

Comment: Your question is not as clear as it could be.  Are you saying that the second line of code is much slower than the first line of code?

Comment: I find both lines take too long. I don't know if it is normal or there is something wrong.

Comment: you're going to have to give a lot more details for us to be able to help you.  I know when I load and save much larger files than 4KB in `openpyxl` it's pretty quick

Comment: So, trhere seems to be something wrong. What details should I add?

Comment: replication procedure would be ideal - including a link to the excel sheet you are loading (also, are you sure it's 4KB?  if you have >67k rows I doubt your file is that small.  If it's 4MB then the timing you are complaining about may make more sense)

Comment: To amplify what @Brad is saying about the size:  When I create a completely empty .xlsx file (Excel 2010 on Windows 7), it's already 8.54 KB.  If I go in and delete the 2nd and 3rd sheets, it still only comes down to 7.16 KB.  So I think 4 MB is very likely while 4 KB is pretty much impossible.

Comment: Indeed, it's 4 MG big.

Answer (score 10):

So I created a 67k row excel sheet with only 4 columns and random decimal data - and the sheet was almost 5MB, so >1000x what you said in your question.  Given that this is a decent amount of data I would suggest using the optimized reader, not the normal one.  Here's a link to the tutorial:

https://openpyxl.readthedocs.org/en/latest/optimized.html

Hopefully this helps!

Comment: Converting XML to Python and back to XML takes time which is why we offer optimisations in the form of `read_only` and `write_only` modes and continue to improve performance wherever possible.

Comment: @Brad what should we do when we have to load the file with this size using load_workbook and add a new row to the worksheet and save the workbook ?